# Failed to install node.js on Debian 7 Wheezy (WM)

Tags: node.js, makefile, debian

I just bought a virtual private server and I'm trying to install the latest version of node (which is node-v4.0.0).

Here what I have done :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install python

wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v4.0.0.tar.gz
tar xfz node-v4.0.0.tar.gz
cd node-v4.0.0

./configure
make
```

Unfortunately, the make failed with this error message :

```
(...)
In file included from ../src/js_stream.h:6:0,
                 from ../src/js_stream.cc:1:
../src/stream_base.h:218:11: error:   overriding ‘virtual node::StreamBase::~StreamBase() noexcept (true)’
make[1]: *** [/root/node-v4.0.0/out/Release/obj.target/node/src/js_stream.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/node-v4.0.0/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

I don't really know how to fix it as I thought Error 2 was caught when you forgot to install any compiler (but I did with build-essential & python, didn't I?)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it downgrading node version to v0.12.7

Comment: Downgrading your version isn't a 'fix'

Comment: Not a real fix, but still useful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have old GCC. Node.js 4.0.0 requires version 4.8 or newer.

Comment: WARNING: C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4 (CXX=g++)
 From the logs, g++ version 4.6 installed, no further updates on debian =/

Comment: @Salakar I met with the same problem. Also C++ compiler too old warning, and then error like in the question. Also on Debian 7 Wheezy. How to upgrade compiler version?

Answer (score -1):

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like a useful answer but it could do with a bit of explanation. E.g. What happens when you run the first line and also why the second line is relevant.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.
This is especially important when recommending that we should execute unseen shell as the `root` user!